# Where is the MultiIndex information stored?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working on data cleaning in pandas and I have created a hierarchical index for ease in subsequent analysis. However, even after creating the MultiIndex (using the `set_index()` function) and exporting the dataset as .csv, I do not notice any change in the dataset when I open the same in Microsoft Excel. It appears exactly the same as before creating the MultiIndex. I am just wondering as to where this information might have been stored (as a metadata, for instance)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no metadata stored. Before exporting the `df` to `excel`, check the `length` of the  `index` of dataframe. If `len(df.index) >1`, your df is a MultiIndex df.

Comment: @MayankPorwal um no? `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]}); print(len(df.index))` will print 3, but that is not a multiindex.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ahh my mistake. I meant `len(df.index.names) > 1`.

Comment: @MayankPorwal thanks for the clarification . I was about to reply the same .